# onEdit updates correctly, but then overwrites following columns after pasting (editing) multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm using Google Spreadsheets and found a script here:

[onEdit only updates top row after pasting (editing) multiple rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/onedit-only-updates-top-row-after-pasting-editing-multiple-rows)

I manipulated the script to fit my needs, and I need it to only look at column 5 when it is updated and then populate the date in column 2.

However when I paste in bulk (which contains an edit in columns > 5), the script puts the date into every column from 2 onwards until it gets to the final offset of -3. This overwrites data

[image]

The script I have so far is as follows:

```
function addtimestampTodata(e) { 
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Data") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
var r = e.range;

if(r.getColumn() == 5) { //checks the column
if(r.getValue() === '') {//don't update the timestamp if the cell is edited to a blank vaue
}
 else
 {
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, -3);
  if(nextCell.getValue() === '') // only update the timestamp if it has not already been updated
  
  {

  var dateTime = new Date();
  // Set the cell
  nextCell.setValue(dateTime);}
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there a way to correct this? I think it's the ranges I'm setting out but can't work out why I set col 5 as the first point of reference, but the script keeps going when other columns are updated too.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Range.offset()` function returns a range that is the *same size* as the original range, rather than a single cell or column, unless you specify optional parameters. You can specify those optional parameters like this:

```
  let nextCell = r.offset(0, -3, r.getHeight(), 1);
```

Note that your code only works correctly when the trigger column `E` is the first column in the range where you paste data.

See [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Comment: The script uses `.getValue()`, so it's only checking the top-left cell of the `nextCell` range. It might require further enhancement (or better to use another script).

Comment: Thank you for taking a look and for your response! Understand now why it wasn't working - I suspected it was to do with the range. I'll dig deeper into the range function to understand it further too.